# Add pop up with background disabled in MVC 4 Jquery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

How do i add pop up to an anchor tag with background disabled in MVC 4 Jquery Mobile? I am new to the MVC 4 and JQuery

Comment: Any ecommerce mobile website with this feature is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Put this content in your style sheet

    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 80%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }


    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }

    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

    and in the code use the following

    <a href="#openModal" target="">Open Modal</a>

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" data-theme="c">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" target="">X</a>
            <h2>Pop up</h2>
            <p>Pop up content. You can add your controls here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

this logic worked for me. Hope it works for you also.
```